# Java Android App

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-sensors, sensormanager

i need your help as fast as possible.
I need to create an java android app,that will switch on the music when shaking a phone.
So at the initial position the sound is switched off and when shaking it, it starts to play.
But when stopping shaking it, the sound switches off. The .mp3 file is already in the project. What's wrong am I doing?

```
package com.authorwjf;
public class Main extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
private float mLastX, mLastY, mLastZ;
private boolean mInitialized;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAccelerometer;
private final float NOISE = (float) 2.0;

//music

MediaPlayer logoMusic;
boolean paused = true;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //music

    logoMusic =  MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.music);
    logoMusic.setVolume(0, 1);
    //

    //
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mInitialized = false;
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // can be safely ignored for this demo
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    TextView tvX= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.x_axis);
    TextView tvY= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.y_axis);
    TextView tvZ= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.z_axis);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    float x = event.values[0];
    float y = event.values[1];
    float z = event.values[2];
    if (!mInitialized) {
        mLastX = x;
        mLastY = y;
        mLastZ = z;
        tvX.setText("0.0");
        tvY.setText("0.0");
        tvZ.setText("0.0");
        mInitialized = true;


    } else {

        float deltaX = Math.abs(mLastX - x);
        float deltaY = Math.abs(mLastY - y);
        float deltaZ = Math.abs(mLastZ - z);
        if (deltaX < NOISE) deltaX = (float)0.0;
        if (deltaY < NOISE) deltaY = (float)0.0;
        if (deltaZ < NOISE) deltaZ = (float)0.0;
        mLastX = x;
        mLastY = y;
        mLastZ = z;
        tvX.setText(Float.toString(deltaX));
        tvY.setText(Float.toString(deltaY));
        tvZ.setText(Float.toString(deltaZ));
        iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (deltaX > deltaY) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.horizontal);
        } else if (deltaY > deltaX) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.vertical);
        } else {
            iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        logoMusic.start();

    }
}
public void pauseMusic( View v ) {
      if (paused)
      {
          logoMusic.start();
          paused = true;
      }
      else
      {
          logoMusic.pause();
          paused = false;
      }
  }


 protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

          logoMusic.start();
    }

    protected void onPause() {

        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);

        super.onPause();
          logoMusic.pause();
    }
```

Comment: try to use "static boolean paused = true;"

Answer (score 0):

You defined your media player, but you never started it. To start it:

```
logoMusic.start();
```